# Check if a string contains a substring. Additionally, get index and number of match (Raku)

Tags: raku

FAQ: In Raku, how to check if a [String](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str) contains a substring ? Where and how many times ?
I would like 3 functions such as:

```
xxx-bool("az and az and az again", "az");  # True 
xxx-num("az and az and az again", "az");   # 3
xxx-list("az and az and az again", "az");  # (0 7 14)
```

PS: Routines [index](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_index) and [rindex](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_rindex) are pretty cool but only get one match.

Related Links:

- [Answer with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596244)
- [Answer on List (Array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763453)
- [Contiguous Sequences on List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926655)
- [Answer on Hash (Dictionary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520727)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. To check if it contains, use [.contains](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_contains) to get a [Bool](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Bool) which is a [cool](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Cool) [method](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Method).
2. To get indices (alias indexes: both are plural of index) use [.indices](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_indices)
3. To get number, count the indices.

```
"az and az and az again".contains("az");        # True
"az and az and az again".indices("az").elems;   # 3
"az and az and az again".indices("az");         # (0 7 14)
```

PS: Routine [indices](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_indices) is described just after [index](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_index) and [rindex](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_rindex). So read the good doc, and read it well ;-)

- Links:

  - [contains in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051427)
  - Same question in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059), [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283274)